Mariabackup fails with SSL Connection error on localhost
I did a fresh (re)install of MariaDB on Windows earlier due to some unrelated issues.
But ever since, I haven't been able to use the mariabackup command. It consistently fails with the following error (time and date irrelevant obviously):
> mariabackup --backup --target-dir=myBackupDir --user=root --password=***
[00] 2024-09-25 09:53:43 Connecting to MariaDB server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: not set
[00] 2024-09-25 09:53:43 Failed to connect to MariaDB server: SSL connection error: SSL certificate is self-signed.

As you can see, this is happening on a localhost connection. I can connect to the database server completely normally with mariadb and other means like IDEs. mariadb-dump is also working fine. The target-dir does not exist but according to all resources I could find, mariabackup would create it if possible.
Searching for this issue seems basically impossible since SSL connection errors seem to mostly happen with remote access/clusters/etc. and not for local access to mariabackup.
I tried setting the TLS/SSL for my root user with REQUIRE NONE to no effect, not sure that was related anyway.
Notably, I do not recall ever having an issue like this in the past when setting up MariaDB on Windows 11. Currently, this is my version:
Server version: 11.5.2-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

I had this version installed previously through updating/upgrading over time from 11.3 > 11.4 > 11.5.
Side note: I did dump my data before the fresh install and all my data is safe. I don't depend on mariabackup working, but I think this is a worthwhile issue to get clarification on at the very least, if not an actual solution.
